# Reading first table and execute the inputs in spark SQL and insert into another table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Please suggest the best possible code for below requirement, we are using the Apache Spark framework.

I have a Table 1 and Table 2, as shown below. First, we need to read table 1 based on Test_id, then execute respective queries (both _SRC and _Target) one after the other and then insert the outputs to table 2 and also do some basic comparison(like <,>,=, etc) with outputs count from table 1 query and write that results to table 2, with the date and user details.

Thanks in advance!

Table 1

[image]

Table 2
[image]

Comment: Is below answer working ??

Comment: Sorry, I forgot last time you asked me test_condition, can you please update your question how you want test_condition column values?

Comment: Table 1 and Table 2 will have similar columns, then Actual_results available in table 1, then it will take that count and compare with the count obtained by the query in column Exetion_script_target then do the comparison based on that like, = or > or <, if it is equal then only it has to update the column Test_result as pass. if not it has updated as Fail. Finally, everything will be updated to Table 2 as a new entry for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below code.

**Creation of Table 1:**

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val df = Seq(
    (1,"select count(*) from dbnameaaa.tbl_name","select count(*) from dbnameaaa.tbl_name"),
    (2,"select count(*) from dbnameaaa.tmp_tbl","select count(*) from dbnameaaa.tmp_tbl"))
    .toDF("test_id","execution_script_src","execution_script_target")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [test_id: int, execution_script_src: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show(false)
+-------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|test_id|execution_script_src                   |execution_script_target                |
+-------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|1      |select count(*) from dbnameaaa.tbl_name|select count(*) from dbnameaaa.tbl_name|
|2      |select count(*) from dbnameaaa.tmp_tbl |select count(*) from dbnameaaa.tmp_tbl |
+-------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

**Creation of Query execution & condition UDFs**

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val execute = udf((query: String) => {
    try { spark.sql(query).map(_.getAs[Long](0)).collect.head }catch { case _: Exception => 0L }
})

val condition = udf((actual:Long,expected:Long) => {
   s"""{"=":"${if (actual == expected) "Pass" else "Fail"}","<":"${if (actual < expected) "Pass" else "Fail"}",">":"${if (actual > expected) "Pass" else "Fail"}","<>":"${if (actual != expected) "Pass" else "Fail"}"}"""
})

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

execute: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,LongType,Some(List(StringType)))
condition: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,StringType,Some(List(LongType, LongType)))
```

**Final table result**

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

df
.withColumn("actual_result",execute($"execution_script_src"))
.withColumn("expected_result",execute($"execution_script_target"))
.withColumn("test_condition",lit("[ =, <, >, <> ]"))
.withColumn("test_result",condition($"actual_result",$"expected_result"))
.withColumn("create_date",current_date)
.withColumn("modify_date",current_date)
.withColumn("created_by",lit(spark.sparkContext.sparkUser))
.withColumn("modified_by",lit(spark.sparkContext.sparkUser))
.withColumn("execute_date",current_date)
.show(false)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

+-------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+
|test_id|execution_script_src                   |execution_script_target                |actual_result|expected_result|test_condition |test_result                                   |create_date|modify_date|created_by|modified_by|execute_date|
+-------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+
|1      |select count(*) from dbnameaaa.tbl_name|select count(*) from dbnameaaa.tbl_name|11           |11             |[ =, <, >, <> ]|{"=":"Pass","<":"Fail",">":"Fail","<>":"Fail"}|2020-05-06 |2020-05-06 |srinivas  |srinivas   |2020-05-06  |
|2      |select count(*) from dbnameaaa.tmp_tbl |select count(*) from dbnameaaa.tmp_tbl |11           |22             |[ =, <, >, <> ]|{"=":"Fail","<":"Pass",">":"Fail","<>":"Pass"}|2020-05-06 |2020-05-06 |srinivas  |srinivas   |2020-05-06  |
+-------+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+-------------+---------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------+-----------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Srinivas, but in my requirement test condition should be any of the one condition and accordingly, it has to update in test_result as pass or fail only.